# How to place two buttons on the same line

Tags: html, cgi

I am using the following code to palce two buttons in a form. But The buttons will come one by one. I mean to say, one button will come first and just below that another button will come.

**code snippet**

```
<form name="myform" action="xxxx.cgi" method="POST">   
<input type="submit" value="hello" name="d">
</form>
<form name="myform" action="yyyy.cgi" method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="hai" name="dd">
</form>
```

I am able to place two buttons in the same row with the following code.

```
<form name="myform" action="xxxx.cgi" method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="hello" name="d">
<input type="submit" value="hai" name="dd">
</form>
```

But both button will be loading xxxx.cgi on click. What can I do to place two buttons on a web page on the same row in which first button will be loading xxxx.cgi on click and second button will be loading yyyy.cgi on click. Please help

By
Dominic

Comment: this isn't an perl qst... imho..

Answer (score 1):

You can use either float:left for form element or you can use display: inline-block

```
form{display: inline-block;}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Add a style like this in your CSS

```
form{
    float:left;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6uzjywo/)

I have used this markup as this is the right one

```
<form name="myform" action="xxxx.cgi" method="POST">   
  <input type="submit" value="hello" name="d">
</form>
<form name="myform" action="yyyy.cgi" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" value="hai" name="dd">
</form>
```

the other one uses two buttons with same name.

One problem with the above code is that it uses two forms in the same page which can create problems sometime.

So use just one form

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6uzjywo/1/) for that..

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<form name="myform" class='myform' action="xxxx.cgi" method="POST">   
    <input type="submit" value="hello" name="d">
</form>
<form name="myform" class='myform' action="yyyy.cgi" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="hai" name="dd">
</form>
```

You can put a style on both forms with the following css.

```
.myform
{
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> hey @Dominic here is what you can do to fix the problem.You just have to use some javascript.
>
> create two forms but place both buttons in one form

```
<body>
<form action='1.php' name='first'>
<input type="button"  value='1.php' id='one'/>
<input type="button"  value='2.php' id='two'/>
</form>
<form action='2.php' name='second'>

</form>
</body>
```

> Trigger actions using javascript

```
var one = document.getElementById('one');
one.onclick=function(){
alert(document.first.submit());
}

var two = document.getElementById('two');
two.onclick=function(){
alert(document.second.submit());
}
```